# Zooming Effect with MKMapView on IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to find some code that will have the following effect. I currently have a map setup in my view, and a button simply named "Zoom Out". Upon clicking this button, I would like the `MKCoordinateSpanMake` to go from `(0.008, 0.008)` to `(0.05, 0.05)`, for example.

Here is the code I have so far:

**AboutMeViewController.swift**

```
import MapKit

class AboutMeViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapOfMySchool: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: XX.4890669,
            longitude: -XX.6993226
        )

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.008, 0.008)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapOfMySchool.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "School Name"
        annotation.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        mapOfMySchool.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomInMap(sender: UIButton) {
        // Zoom code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
@IBAction func zoomInMap(sender: UIButton) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: XX.4890669,
        longitude: -XX.6993226
    )
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapOfMySchool.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

I would also suggest changing the call in `viewDidLoad` to be unanimated since it won't be visible to the user anyway.